# Using variable in form fields of laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to use a variable in a javascript function written as `onClick` attribute in `button` element but it's not working out

The javascript function I am trying to trigger when user click on the `button` element

```
updateForm(variableHere);
```

Variable is `$dealer->id`

This is how I am trying to do

```
@if ($dealer->user->activated==true)
    {{ sprintf(Form::button('%s', ['class' => 'edit', 'style' => 'border: none; background: none; padding: 0px;', 'onClick' => 'updateForm(%s)']),'<i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>', '{{{ $dealer->id }}}')  }}
@endif
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['dealers.status', $dealer->id], 'id' => 'update-status-'.$dealer->id ]) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

but getting this when I check the element's source code

```
<button fa-eye-slash"="" fa="" onclick="updateForm(&lt;i class=" style="border: none; background: none; padding: 0px;" class="edit">)" type="button"&gt;<!--?php echo e($dealer--->id); ?&gt;</button>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the data passed to `sprintf` is backwards. Since the data used to fill in the attributes comes before the data to place into the button element, you would need to switch the second and third parameters.

Second, attempting to pass in the dealer variable like that will actually print out the PHP code, instead of executing it, so you would need to get rid of the blade syntax surrounding it.

Third, I think a better method to do what you're looking to do is to use the `HTML::decode()` method, instead of `sprintf`:

```
@if ($dealer->user->activated==true)
    {{ HTML::decode(Form::button('<i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>', ['class' => 'edit', 'style' => 'border: none; background: none; padding: 0px;', 'onClick' => 'updateForm('.$dealer->id.')'])) }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution and feels like stupid

I can simple use it like this `updateForm('.$dealer->id.')` instead of calling sprintf function on `updateForm()`

so I just need to change it to this

```
@if ($dealer->user->activated==true)
    {{ sprintf(Form::button('%s', ['class' => 'edit', 'style' => 'border: none; background: none; padding: 0px;', 'onClick' => 'updateForm('.$dealer->id.')']),'<i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>')  }}
@endif
    {{ Form::open(['route' => ['dealers.status', $dealer->id], 'id' => 'update-status-'.$dealer->id ]) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```